# How to get object from database using sqlMap?

Tags: spring, ibatis

I want to insert and get object from database using sqlMap. insert user is working fine but when i call getUser it throw an exception "Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException".

### SqlUserDaoImpl

```
public void insertUser(User user)
{
    try
    {
        getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert("User.insert", user);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public User getUser(String email) {
    User user=null;
    try 
    {
        user = (User) getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("User.getUser", email);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return user;
}
```

---

### User.xml

```
<sqlMap namespace="User">
    <select id="getUser" resultClass="MyProject.domain.User">
        select userName as name, password as password, email as email from users where email = #value#
    </select>

    <insert id="insert" parameterClass="MyProject.domain.User">
        insert into users (userName,password,email) values
        (#name#,#password#,#email#)
    </insert>
</sqlMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you sqlmap you are not specifying the parameterClass for the getUser statement; try adding:

```
parameterClass="string"
```

to your statement.